# Quartus II use file only in simulation

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

I want to run a simulation in Quartus. So I assign a Testbench in the Assignment menu. My testbench includes my DUT(D) and a extra component(E), which is only for simulation (so this component includes statements which are not syntesizeable). My simulation runs if I remove E from my Testbench, but when I want to include E in my Testbench, I get the error from modelsim:

```
 my_testbench.vhd(197): (vcom-1195) cannot find expanded name "mylib.only_for_simulation".
```

How could I make Quartus/Modelsim to compile the E file?

Comment: Is the extra component written in the testbench file or a separate file?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't compiled `only_for_simulation` into `mylib`. Did you compile it into the default `work` library by mistake?

Comment: @MartinZabel : yeah, its in an extra file
@BrianDrummond : I added it into `mylib`. If I go to the `Design Units` view, this file is in the right library. But maybe it don't compile. How to say Quartus to compile this file also only for simulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start a simulation, Quartus **analyzes all** files specified in the project settings (accessible via menu Assignment -> Settings -> Files). But, it **elaborates only** the entities which are required for the DUT starting from the top-level entity (see menu Assignment -> Settings -> General). 
For example, in my test project `top` specifies the entity of the DUT, and `my_testbench` and `only_for_simulation` are required for simulation only. This is the output from Quartus in the messages window after starting the simulation:

> Info (12021): Found 2 design units, including 1 entities, in source
>   file my_testbench.vhdl
>
> Info (12021): Found 2 design units, including 1 entities, in source
>   file top.vhdl
>
> Info (12021): Found 2 design units, including 1 entities, in source
>   file only_for_simulation.vhdl
>
> Info (12127): Elaborating entity "top" for the top level hierarchy

Only the files which store the entities found during **elaboration** are added automatically to the script to start the ModelSim simulator. Thus, it doesn't matter if `my_testbench` and `only_for_simulation` are listed as project files. Further simulation files must be *always* specified in the **test-bench setup** accessible via menu Assignment -> Settings -> Simulation -> Compile test bench -> Test Benches -> New/Edit. There, you have to list the files storing `my_testbench` and `only_for_simulation`. And you have to list them in the *right compilation order*, that is, `only_for_simulation` before `my_testbench`. Within this dialog, you can also set the library of `only_for_simulation` to `mylib` via Properties. Here, is a screenshot of the my test-bench setup.

[image: test-bench setup]

The generated ModelSim script is stored in the sub-directory simulation/modelsim in file with extension `.do`. It lists all files to be compiled by ModelSim. And ModelSim compiles them in the given order only.

Comment: Thank you! Thats exactly I need. Do you figure that out by trying it (thats including knowing it because of spending so much time with Quartus ;) or is there in any WP or AppNote a chapter about this thing?

Comment: I'm doing a lot of FPGA design with Quartus, so that, the first part of my answer was already in my mind. I have just to check if setting a library name for one of the simulation files also works. I can't say if there is a good WP or AppNote on this topic.