# VHDL - Testbench internal signals

Tags: vhdl, modelsim, quartus

I am spending some time learning about writing test benches to try out on some of the models I have produced. Does anyone know a way to monitor signals that are internal to the architecture of the unit under test. I have tried using

```
LIBRARY MODELSIM_LIB;
USE MODELSIM_LIB.UTIL.ALL;
    spy_process : process begin
        init_signal_spy("Q4/C1/A1/chip_sel","/chip_sel",1);
        wait;
        end process spy_process;
```

But I get a compiler error of the :

> Error (10481): VHDL Use Clause error at Q4.vhd(15): design library "MODELSIM_lib" does not contain primary unit "util"

I've checked the Quartus II library folder and util is there in the correct place.
Any suggestions?
Thanks D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start a simulation, Quartus **analyzes all** files specified in the project settings (accessible via menu Assignment -> Settings -> Files). But, it **elaborates only** the entities which are required for the DUT starting from the top-level entity (see menu Assignment -> Settings -> General) to find out which design files (excluding testbenches) are required for simulation.
For more details, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837658/5466118).

The library `MODELSIM_LIB` is found by ModelSim only, not by Quartus. Thus, Quartus-II fails to analyze your testbench file with the error posted in the question. But this is actually not required because it (should) only contain testbench code. Thus:

1. remove this testbench file from your Quartus project via menu Project -> "Add/Remove Files in Project...", and
2. add this file only in the simulation settings accessible via menu Assignment -> Settings -> Simulation -> Compile test bench -> Test Benches -> New/Edit.

Comment: Not sure if I get you. I tried the steps you mentioned. made a separate file containing the test bench model. and removed it from the project. Then used it in the settings/simulation compile test bench section. Which worked fine. I get the option in modish to run the test bench. still no internal signals. If I add the code from the original question then the test bench is not usable when I run the simulation

Comment: @DannyJ I havn't used signal spy before. Thus. I checked only to load the `MODELSIM_LIB`. My solution fixes the error and thus answers the main part of the question. Could you make minimal and complete example to check for the `init_signal_spy`?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are using Modelsim to simulate, in which case you should not need anything more than to use the **signal spy** in VHDL, here is an example (excuse any syntax errors)...

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity my_testbench is

end my_testbench;

architecture behavioral of my_testbench is

    signal spy_blob : std_logic := '0';

begin

    my_entity : entity work.my_entity(rtl)
        port map(
            ...
            );

    spy_blob <= << signal .my_testbench.my_entity.w_blob : std_logic >>;

    my_monitor : process(w_clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(w_clk)) then
            if(spy_blob = '1') then
                -- do something
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end behavioral;
```

**Note:** this works with V13 of Quartus/Modelsim package.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this out but just get a compiler error with the syntax for spy_blob <= << signal .T1.rom.chip_sel : std_logic>>